# how to deploy a custom skeleton application in Bluemix php

Tags: php, httpd.conf, ibm-cloud

In Bluemix if I create an application starting from php template then the DocumentRoot is set to:

`/htdocs`.

I actually would like to have a dir structure like this:

```
/htdocs
    /public_html
        index.php
    /myCode
        myPhpClass.php
```

with httpd.conf DocumentRoot="${HOME}/htdocs/public_html".

So I tried to push this community buildpack https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack.git from my local myAppName dir:

```
   /var
      /www
         /myAppName
             /public_html
                 index.php
             /myCode
                 myOhoClass.php
             /.bp-config
                 options.json
```

using cf:

```
[... myAppName]# cf push -s cflinuxfs2 -m 128M -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack.git myAppName
```

where options.json file:

```
{
    "WEBDIR": "htdocs/public_html"
}
```

but what I ended to get in Bluemix is:

```
 /htdocs
        /public_html
            /public_html
                index.php
            /myCode
                myPhpClass.php
```

Is there a way to have a custom directory structure for an apache httpd/php application in Bluemix?

Answer (score 2):

Your `.bp-config/options.json` file is a little wrong.  It should be the following.

```
{
    "WEBDIR": "public_html"
}
```

I just tried things myself with a PHP app and it worked fine.

```
cf push php-test-jbs -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack.git -s cflinuxfs2
```

Additionally to deploy the sample click the following.

[image: Deploy to Bluemix]

or goto the [Github project](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/php-app-with-custom-web-root.git) to check out a full sample.

[image]

Comment: Sorry maybe it wasn't clear in my question, but that is exactly what I did. The problem is not that options aren't deployed, but that I don't know how to use options to create the required skeleton application.

Comment: That creates this structure: /public_html/index.php not the desired structure:  /htdocs/public_html/index.php (with DocumentRoot pointing to public_html).

Comment: I'd like to replicate in Bluemix my dev server directory tree: Apache serving files placed in [/var/www]/htdocs/public_html/ while php classes and other stuff that I don't want in the public directory to be placed in [/var/www]/htdocs/myCode/ (the part included in square brackets [ ] is just in local server, while Bluemix should have a different one).

Comment: I think this is a popular dirs structure in php apps. Thanks.

Comment: @marcoe isn't that what I posted in my answer? See above picture.

Comment: Yes and not Jeff: in your tree is missing the /htdocs/ branch and /myCode as well as /public_html are placed at the same tree level of Bluemix stuff like /httpd and /php, and instead I'd prefer to have a /htdocs dir that contains all and only all my application, leaving Bluemix directories at an upper level. So the point is: to set DocumentRoot in httpd.conf in a choosen directory that is not necessarily the first in the tree like you can do with WEBDIR par.

Comment: I only liked to have it for ease of visualization: that is how things are organized in my php Eclipse projects. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I upvoted but prferred to keep it open in case somebody has a solution to do it even if maybe there's no need to do it. Thanks again.